# Series expansion logistic distribution

Tags: calculus, probability

Probably my question is very elementary. But, I wonder if anyone can explain the procedure to transform this expression used in this question: [Compute variance of logistic distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267635/compute-variance-of-logistic-distribution)

\begin{equation*}
f(x)=2 \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{x^{2}e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^{2}}dx
\end{equation*}
Into this: 
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=2\int^{\infty}_{0}x^{2}\sum^{\infty}_{0}n(-1)^{n-1}e^{-nx}dx
\end{equation*}
I know there involved some form of expansion, but do not get the desired result.
I appreciate any help in this regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $$(1-z)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k.$$  Formal differentiation of this power series yields $$(1-z)^{-2} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty kz^{k-1}.$$  Then letting $z = -e^{-x}$ gives $$e^{-x} (1+e^{-x})^{-2} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-x} k (-e^{-x})^{k-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k (-1)^{k-1} e^{-kx},$$ as claimed.