# Given PDF find Mean of the distribution

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

pdf: 
$
f(x) = \frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2}
$

Find the mean of the distribution using: 
$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x) \ \mathrm{d}x
$

Is it possible?

I have run the integral in a calculator only to find out that it diverges.

I got: 
$
\int x\frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2} \ \mathrm{d}x = \frac{x}{1+e^{-x}}-\ln \left|e^{-x}+1\right|+C
$

which should basically diverge. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Maple says the result is zero.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thank You! turns out as I switched the calculator I too got the same result (=0). Interestingly $\int xf(x)dx$ is symmetric about y- axis, so the mean must be zero.

Comment: Density is symmetric about zero, so of course mean (which exists) equals zero.

Comment: Also asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2849517/how-to-calculate-mean-and-variance-for-logistic-distribution.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks a ton! that was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, notice that $|e^{-x}+1| = e^{-x}+1.$ Moreover, observe that for any $a > 0$:

$$\int_{-a}^a x\frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2} \ \mathrm{d}x = -\left[\log(e^{-x} + 1) + \frac{x}{e^{x} + 1}\right]_{x=-a}^{x=a} = \\
-\left[\log(e^{-a} + 1) + \frac{a}{e^{a} + 1} - \log(e^{a} + 1) - \frac{-a}{e^{-a} + 1}\right] = \\
-\left[\log\left(\frac{e^{-a} + 1}{e^{a} + 1}\right) + \frac{a}{e^{a} + 1} + \frac{a}{e^{-a} + 1}\right] = \\
-\left[\log\left(\frac{e^{-a}(e^{a} + 1)}{e^{a} + 1}\right) + \frac{a}{e^{a} + 1} + \frac{ae^{a}}{e^{a}(e^{-a} + 1)}\right] = \\
-\left[\log e^{-a} + \frac{a}{e^{a} + 1} + \frac{ae^{a}}{e^{a} + 1}\right] = \\
-\left[-a + \frac{a(e^a + 1)}{e^{a} + 1} \right] = -[-a+a] = 0.\\
$$